# Fill down blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I got code to fill the blank cells in a column of data.

It works the first time. However, after having filled all those blank cells, it is still looking for blank cells.

It is throwing an error:

> Run-time error '1004' "No cells were found".

How could I change this code so it fills blank cells only if there are blank cells?

```vb
Sub FillRow()

S_Data.Activate
LR = S_Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

S_Data.Range("H2:H" & LR).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

End Sub
```

I tried scripts I found online, including `For` loops and `If` `Then`, but wasn't able to get these to work.

Comment: My guess .... I think the error itself describe `"No cells were found"`. So, in your selection there is no blank cell. Consequently when you command to select a blank cell in your selection which has no blank cell, it say something like this _hey, there is no blank cell in your selection, so we can't select a blank cell in a selection which has no blank cell_ :). So in this `S_Data.Range("H2:H" & LR).Select` ---> there is no blank cell within H2 to H nth row. Therefore `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select` throw you an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trap or ignore the error when there are no blanks in the range:

```vb
Sub FillRow()
    Dim rng As Range, LR As Long
    
    LR = S_Data.Cells(S_Data.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no blanks
    Set rng = S_Data.Range("H2:H" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    'any blank cells?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Bless you, this worked perfectly! Thanks so much, I was going crazy trying to get this to work and now it's all set. Thank you!!